# Select tag doesn't display on my form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, select

I'm writing a really simple form with 2 text fields and one select. For some reason, the select tag with options doesn't display on my page. I can see the 2 text fields and the label for the the select, but not the select it self.
The app is written in rails and I use materialize.

There might be something too obvious that I don't see it, but after 30mn of thinking, I guess it's fair to put it on SO :)
Thanks

Here's the code:

```
<form action="/resources" method="post">

  <input
  type="hidden"
  name="authenticity_token"
  value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>">

  <label for="ressource_name">Ressource Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="ressource_name" name="resource[ress_name]" value="<%= @resource.ress_name %>">

  <label for="ressource_link">Ressource Link</label>
  <input type="text" id="ressource_link" name="resource[link]" value="<%= @resource.link %>">


  <label for="categories">Categories</label>
  <select id="categories" name="resource[category_id]">
    <option value="1">Stuff 1</option>
    <option value="2">Stuff 2</option>
    <option value="3">Stuff 3</option>
    <option value="4">Stuff 4</option>
    <option value="5">Stuff 5</option>
    <option value="6">Stuff 6</option>
    <option value="7">Stuff 7</option>
    <option value="8">Stuff 8</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Post">
</form>
```

Comment: There might be some other issue, Might be styling problem. Because i can able to see the select box. Check the styling for the select box. might be through query it is hiding.

Comment: You're right, for some reason the display was set to none... Thanks Samir :)

Comment: Welcome. Here for you any time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So I put the answer (from Samir) here as well as I guess some other people might come across that issue (it won't change your life, but it might save you some minutes that you want to spend on 'real' issues).

Check the styling! For some reason the select tag was defaulted to {display: none;}

Answer (score 8):

The select tags(likely all select tags)  on your page are most likely defaulted to styled to 'display : none' and just in case you cannot find the exact css code that is disappearing the select tag, just cascade the old style by declaring a style attribute on the select element and display it to block. like below

```
<select style="display: block;">
    <option value="" selected>Choose Country</option>
</select>
```